# Launcher that displays numbers in place of Android Notification dots

Tags: android, launcher

I like how Notification dots work on Android but ideally I want a number to display in the same manor as the dots.  Most launchers that implement numbers display a native count number which I do not want because few app actually support this in my experience.  I am running a Pixel on Oreo.  I'm not concerned about the price really, but hate ads.

[image]

Comment: A few more details would help us understand what you are looking for – e.g. device and Android version (some apps have restrictions there). Screenshots would help a lot as well as sketches, to visualize what you see now, and what you want to have instead. Moreover: what's the price tag? Or must it come for free / open source? Are ads/trackers acceptable?

Comment: Did you try [Nova Launcher Prime](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher.prime)? I use it. Though I don't need notification counts it works

Comment: @beeshyams I use nova launcher prime currently because it is closest